# Magento 2 show price range for configurable product on category page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, configurable-product

I have configurable products with different prices for each product. For example I have a configurable product with three package sizes:

- Small = 50$
- Medium = 60$
- Large = 70$

On the category page, the price of this product will show as "50$".

I want to show either:

- The price range: "50$ - 70$"
- A "from" text: "From 50$"

Is it possible to show the price range of all the configurable products?

Comment: Ye, same issue, started looking into the price renderers but it's a pretty deep rabbit hole. I'm currently no closer to a solution and losing the will to live, will let you know if I come up with out.

Comment: Thanks. Likewise, i will pursue the dream of a solution and let you know.

Comment: @Chedaroo Any updates?

Comment: Here is well described solution to make that https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/196984/2282

Comment: @FireBear weird how the duplicate is more recent and got more attention