# Magento 2 display configurable Price Range in product listing

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, category-listing, magento-2.1.9

I want to display price range for configurable products instead of the minimal price in category listing.
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to pluginize **getProductPrice** method.

**SR/Stackexchange/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="SR_Stackexchange:price_range" type="SR\Stackexchange\Plugin\Block\Product\ListProduct" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**SR/Stackexchange/Plugin/Block/Product/ListProduct.php**

```
namespace SR\Stackexchange\Plugin\Block\Product;

use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;

class ListProduct
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
     */
    protected $listProductBlock;

    /**
     * @var Configurable
     */
    protected $configurableProduct;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $pricingHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * ListProduct constructor.
     *
     * @param Configurable $configurableProduct
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        Configurable $configurableProduct,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->configurableProduct = $configurableProduct;
        $this->pricingHelper = $pricingHelper;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundGetProductPrice(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {

        if (Configurable::TYPE_CODE !== $product->getTypeId()) {
            return $proceed($product);
        }

        $this->listProductBlock = $subject;
        $priceText = $this->getPriceRange($product);

        return $priceText;
    }

    /**
     * Get configurable product price range
     *
     * @param $product
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPriceRange($product)
    {
        $childProductPrice = [];
        $childProducts = $this->configurableProduct->getUsedProducts($product);
        foreach($childProducts as $child) {
            $price = number_format($child->getPrice(), 2, '.', '');
            $finalPrice = number_format($child->getFinalPrice(), 2, '.', '');
            if($price == $finalPrice) {
                $childProductPrice[] = $price;
            } else if($finalPrice < $price) {
                $childProductPrice[] = $finalPrice;
            }
        }

        $max = $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore(max($childProductPrice));
        $min = $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore(min($childProductPrice));
        if($min==$max){
            return $this->getPriceRender($product, "$min", '');
        } else {
            return $this->getPriceRender($product, "$min-$max", '');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Price renderer
     *
     * @param $product
     * @param $price
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getPriceRender($product, $price, $text='')
    {
        return $this->listProductBlock->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
            ->setTemplate('SR_Stackexchange::product/price/range/price.phtml')
            ->setData('price_id', 'product-price-'.$product->getId())
            ->setData('display_label', $text)
            ->setData('product_id', $product->getId())
            ->setData('display_value', $price)->toHtml();
    }
}
```

**SR/Stackexchange/view/frontend/templates/product/price/range/price.phtml**

```
<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>

<div class="price-box range second price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductId() ?>">
    <span class="special-price">
        <span class="price-container price-final_price">
            <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
                <span class="price-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayLabel(); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
                data-price-amount=""
                data-price-type="finalPrice1"
                class="price-wrapper">
                <span class="price"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayValue();?></span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Clear Cache.

Comment: Shows some error in this area
else if($finalPrice pricingHelper->currencyByStore(max($childProductPrice));
        $min = $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore(min($childProductPrice));

Comment: Also some error in the phtml file.

Comment: Show your error. It's tested code and working fine.

Comment: Check updated code for SR/Stackexchange/view/frontend/templates/product/price/range/price.phtml

Comment: http://i.prntscr.com/2prpepuBRqi1PuBpnq8BOg.png
please check following area in ListProduct.php. My editor shows error in this area.
else if($finalPrice pricingHelper->currencyByStore(max($childProductPrice)); $min = $this->pricingHelper->currencyByStore(min($childProductPrice‌​))

Comment: It was < decode problem. Check updated answer. clear cache.

Comment: I want to display the price range in recently viewed and related products list. How can I do it?

Comment: What is supposed to mean SR/Stackexchange ? the base of an registrable module? a folder in "vendor"? (sorry, I only know those 2 options to extend)
Thanks

Comment: SR/Stackexchange = VendorName/ModuleName, Location should be app/code/ @MarioM.

Comment: @SohelRana I have set configurable product, after select dropdown value the price change to "0", how can i solve this issue,

Comment: @SohelRana how to display the same concept on PDP?

Comment: example: https://prnt.sc/ruosqz  we would like to display the price range

Comment: @SohelRana https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309861/magento2-display-price-range-on-pdp-configrable-product can u help me on this?

Comment: @SohelRana can u advise on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310131/magento2-display-configurable-product-price-range-on-wishlist-page