# How to show configurable price range on product list page & product page?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I am trying to figure out how I can show a price range on the category list pages & product pages for configurable products.

For example I have a configurable product with three package sizes:

Small = 10$,
 Medium = 15$,
 Large = 20$

On the category page, the price of this product will show as "10$".

I want to show:

The price range: "10$ - 20$".

Thanks!

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196961/magento-2-display-configurable-price-range-in-product-listing/196984#196984

Comment: Thanks, how do I show this range on the product page too?