# Configurable products price starting from price magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

How can I show price start range on category list page and detail page of configurable products in magento 2.

Comment: You can refer this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196961/magento-2-display-configurable-price-range-in-product-listing

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom **Plugin** for this:

Similar question has been answered here: [SEE LINK](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196961/magento-2-display-configurable-price-range-in-product-listing)